# Get last number out of a cell with multiple numbers

Tags: r

I have a datatable in R with a column that contains multiple values separated by a comma and I would like to extract the last value from each row in that column. However, the number of values in the different rows vary. Some times there are 3 or 4 values separated by commas and sometimes there is only one. I always need the last value.

The rows look basically like this.

```
[1.848]     
[0.207,0.403]   
[0.3,0.29]      
[0.948,3.064]       
[0.431,0.431,0.214] 
[0.305,0.305,0.30]  
[0.213,0.42]    
[0.31,0.30]     
[1.484,2.433]
```

That would be my preferred outcome:

```
1.848   
0.403
0.29        
3.064   
0.214   
0.30    
0.42    
0.30    
2.433
```

Comment: Do you really have `[]` in your data ? You can use `dput(head(df, 10))` to share first 10 rows of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R approach using `sub` to extract the last number within `[]`.

```
df$col2 <- as.numeric(sub('\\[.*(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\]', '\\1', df$col1))
df

#                 col1  col2
#1             [1.848] 1.848
#2       [0.207,0.403] 0.403
#3          [0.3,0.29] 0.290
#4       [0.948,3.064] 3.064
#5 [0.431,0.431,0.214] 0.214
#6  [0.305,0.305,0.30] 0.300
#7        [0.213,0.42] 0.420
#8         [0.31,0.30] 0.300
#9       [1.484,2.433] 2.433
```

If there is no `[]` in your actual data, this would work.

```
df$col2 <- as.numeric(sub('.*(\\d+\\.\\d+)', '\\1', df$col1))
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `trimws` from `base R`

```
df1$col1 <- as.numeric(trimws(df1$col1, whitespace = ".*,|[][]"))
```

-output

```
> df1
   col1
1 1.848
2 0.403
3 0.290
4 3.064
5 0.214
6 0.300
7 0.420
8 0.300
9 2.433
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("[1.848]", "[0.207,0.403]", "[0.3,0.29]", 
"[0.948,3.064]", "[0.431,0.431,0.214]", "[0.305,0.305,0.30]", 
"[0.213,0.42]", "[0.31,0.30]", "[1.484,2.433]")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `separate_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
    separate_rows(col1) %>% 
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
    na.omit () %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter(col1 == last(col1)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-id)
```

output:

```
   col1
  <dbl>
1 1.85 
2 0.403
3 0.29 
4 3.06 
5 0.214
6 0.3  
7 0.42 
8 0.3  
9 2.43
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution that I use `,` as reference to get the last number.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
    
x <- c("1.848", "0.207,0.403", "0.3,0.29", "0.948,3.064", "0.431,0.431,0.214", 
       "0.305,0.305,0.30", "0.213,0.42", "0.31,0.30", "1.484,2.433")
    
df <- tibble(x = x)

last_number <- function(x){
  as.numeric(word(x,str_count(x,",") + 1,sep = ","))
}

df %>% 
  mutate(last_number = last_number(x))

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  x                 last_number
  <chr>                   <dbl>
1 1.848                   1.85 
2 0.207,0.403             0.403
3 0.3,0.29                0.29 
4 0.948,3.064             3.06 
5 0.431,0.431,0.214       0.214
6 0.305,0.305,0.30        0.3  
7 0.213,0.42              0.42 
8 0.31,0.30               0.3  
9 1.484,2.433             2.43
```